# Estimativas da regressão ordinal com sinal trocado

Tags: r, regressão

Estou tentando reproducir os resultados que estão no livro An introduction to Generalized Linear Models third edition of Dobson and Barnett, na pagina 161. O ajuste é uma regressão ordinal aplicado a conjunto de dados [(link para download)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7afvvkp5q65semy/car.xls?dl=0). Minha grande confusão é que os resultados numéricos são os mesmos mais o sinal é oposta, eu acho que tem que ver a reparametrização, mas não tenho certeza. Segue o código que usei e também deixo as imagens das estimativas apresentadas no livro e as estimativas que eu obtive. Agradeço os possíveis comentários do que está acontecendo.

```
library(readxl) #para usar la función "read_excel"

car_pref <- read_excel('car.xls')
car_pref <- car_pref[-1,]
car_pref <- car_pref[-1,]
colnames(car_pref) <- c("sex","age","response","frequency")
car_pref$frequency <- as.numeric(car_pref$frequency)
car_pref$sex       <- factor(car_pref$sex)
car_pref$age       <- factor(car_pref$age)
car_pref$response  <- factor(car_pref$response)

car_pref$sex       <- relevel(car_pref$sex, ref="women")
car_pref$age       <- relevel(car_pref$age, ref="24-40")
car_pref$age       <- relevel(car_pref$age, ref="18-23")
car_pref$response  <- relevel(car_pref$response, ref="very important")

library(MASS) 

res.polr <- polr(factor(response)~factor(age) + factor(sex), weights=frequency,data=car_pref)
summary(res.polr)
```

Resultados do livro
[image: image of the book]

Meus resultados

[image]

Veja que as estimações são numericamente as mesmas mais o sinal é oposto.

O código que o livro apresenta é

```
res.polr <- polr(factor(response)~factor(age) + factor(sex), weights=frequency,data=car_pref)
```

mais utilizando isso não obtenho a saída que apresenta o livro.

Comment: Eu não tenho uma resposta definitiva para te dar, mas algumas sugestões de onde procurar maneiras de tentar descobrir o que se passa. Dei uma olhada aqui no livro e, nesta mesma página 161, os autores também fornecem o código do ajuste do modelo para o STATA. Será que na tabela com os coeficientes eles não reportaram o output do STATA em vez do R? Outra hipótese a ser considerada é a própria função de verossimilhança a ser maximizada. Talvez seja uma diferença no sinal entre a função do R e do STATA?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sugestão @MarcusNunes.

Comment: Já entendi que esta acontecendo, acontece que o livro não esta fazendo uso da parametrização que faz o R, ou seja o modelo ordinal parametrizado consideran o sinal oposto, tal como  [link](http://bit.ly/2QDSqtP). No livro do Agresti 2010, Analysis of Ordinal Categorical Data pag. 49 o autor fala sobre dita parametrização.